# ReactJS Insert RAW html with function (onClick)

Tags: html, reactjs, render

Hello is posible with react render with

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.test}} />
```

when rendered html is like

```
this.state = {
      test: "<button onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>test</button>"
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason for assigning html to a state prop instead of a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this, but if you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML then I think it is exactly like if the string was hard-coded into an HTML file, i.e. `onClick` should be `onclick` (lowercase) and the handler function needs to be quoted and will be in the global document window scope. That's probably not what you want.

It would make more sense to store the info needed to render your content as a state object, and create the `<button>` as a regular react element.

```
this.state = {
      type: 'button',
      handler: this.test.bind(this),
      text : 'test'
}
...
renderElement(){
  const {type, handler, text} = this.state
  if(type === 'button'){
     return <button onClick={handler}>{text}</button>
  }
}
...
render(){
   <div>{this.renderElement()</div>
}
```

Comment: I got the SVG map stored in database and just need to add click methods

Comment: Could you wrap your SVG in a react (not DOM) <div> element and then just bind the click handler to that the normal way?

Comment: yeap I did it this way, so I load the SVG map and then by addEvenetListener bind functions by ID, si its solved for me :)